# How to expose microservice application APIs to external developers

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway

My web application is built on micro-services (AWS Lambda). For in-app use we make call to the API Gateway rest api where the JWT is authenticated by a custom lambda authorizer and then based on which service the api call is made to, the respective Lambda processes it.

To give an example, lets assume I have a School administration app, where each business logic is divided into its own microservice.

So anything to do with `students` is handled by `student-lambda` which can be called using the endpoint `https://students-api-service.mydomain.com/api/{+proxy}`

For administrative service, the front end will call `https://administration-api-service.mydomain.com/api/{+proxy}`

You get the point.

Now I need to expose some functionalities of my services to create a public API, where external developers can register with us and call our API from their application (like an integration with us).

I don't want to expose the current APIs for mainly two reasons.

1. Each service will have its own route 53 record which will get confusing to the users. I would rather have a single domain from where I can serve request; something like

`https://api.mydomain.com/api/students`

`https://api.mydomain.com/api/administration`

2. I want to place another authorizer which is only used for developer authorization and has nothing to do with normal user.
3. Right now, none of my lambdas have any reserved concurrency setup. For developer usage I will need to reduce (or least remove) the cold start timing issue for faster delivery + add some level of API throttling and rate limiting.

What are my possible options? I do not want to rewrite the business logic in my microservices in a mono-repo/server cause it will mean maintaining code twice.

Another idea I had was to create one lambda for any api calls and call other lambdas from within to return the data. Is there any other respectable way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a new public API Gateway, as a single API with mappings to all your current Lambda functions. You would configure this new API Gateway with [usage plans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) that require API keys. You would generate a new API key for each developer that needs to access the API. That would give each developer access to the API without further authentication steps, and enforce rate limits on each developer.

As for the reserved concurrency issue, that is purely a detail of how you are deploying your Lambda functions, not really related to who is accessing the functions, or how they are being accessed. Unless you want to deploy an entire second copy of all your functions just to enable reserved concurrency, you probably just need to configure reserved concurrency for your current Lambda function deployments.

Comment: I think you are referring to this: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api. But it seems the api keys will be auto generated upon deployment and printed on screen. I won't be able to generate them myself via a developer registration UI. Also if I need to add more keys, I will need to redeploy it?

Comment: I'm not talking about using the serverless framework at all. I'm talking about this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html Which you can absolutely do in your developer registration UI by having your back-end code call the AWS API to generate a key https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-restapi.html